# Интеграция в системное меню андроида

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Непонятно, как интегрировать свой пункт меню в системное меню андроида. Например, как добавить новый пункт (или любой другой виджет) в меню управления wi-fi или bluetooth соединениями? Подскажите где смотреть, может имеются примеры кода.

Comment: В англоязычном SO пишут, что нельзя. Через левое ухо правой ногой только для своего приложения, а для телефона в целом никак. Рейтинг у ответчиков, как у сами знаете кого :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559405/android-add-item-to-global-context-menu

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Только если свою прошивку сделать.

Comment: А где про это можно прочесть?

Answer (score 0):

[Android Sources](http://source.android.com/)
Пока репозитарии лежат, насколько мне известно.